# How does this "StickyScrollView" implementation stick the view to the top of the ScrollView?

Tags: android

Typically how sticky headers work is that there's some sort of scrollable data that is divided into sections, each with their own header, and as you scroll down, the headers of subsequent sections replace the header at the top of the `ScrollView`.

What I need is to have *additional* sticky headers within each respective section. For example, if `header1` is stuck to the top, its first section's header --`header1a`-- is stuck underneath it, but when we get to section `1b`, `1b's` header will replace `1a's`, but leaving `header1` stuck in the same place; and when we finally get to section `2`, `header2` will replace the currently stuck headers from the previous section -- `header1` and `header1b`.

Here is a `ScrollView` implementation that implements sticky headers in a one-dimensional fashion:
https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author Emil Sj�lander - sjolander.emil@gmail.com
 *
 */
public class StickyScrollView extends ScrollView {

    /**
     * Tag for views that should stick and have constant drawing. e.g. TextViews, ImageViews etc
     */
    public static final String STICKY_TAG = "sticky";

    /**
     * Flag for views that should stick and have non-constant drawing. e.g. Buttons, ProgressBars etc
     */
    public static final String FLAG_NONCONSTANT = "-nonconstant";

    /**
     * Flag for views that have aren't fully opaque
     */
    public static final String FLAG_HASTRANSPARANCY = "-hastransparancy";

    /**
     * Default height of the shadow peeking out below the stuck view.
     */
    private static final int DEFAULT_SHADOW_HEIGHT = 10; // dp;

    private ArrayList<View> mStickyViews;
    private View mCurrentlyStickingView;
    private float mStickyViewTopOffset;
    private int mStickyViewLeftOffset;
    private boolean mRedirectTouchesToStickyView;
    private boolean mClippingToPadding;
    private boolean mClipToPaddingHasBeenSet;

    private int mShadowHeight;
    private Drawable mShadowDrawable;

    private final Runnable mInvalidateRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(mCurrentlyStickingView !=null){
                int l = getLeftForViewRelativeOnlyChild(mCurrentlyStickingView);
                int t  = getBottomForViewRelativeOnlyChild(mCurrentlyStickingView);
                int r = getRightForViewRelativeOnlyChild(mCurrentlyStickingView);
                int b = (int) (getScrollY() + (mCurrentlyStickingView.getHeight() + mStickyViewTopOffset));
                invalidate(l,t,r,b);
            }
            postDelayed(this, 16);
        }
    };

    public StickyScrollView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public StickyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.scrollViewStyle);
    }

    public StickyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setup();



        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.StickyScrollView, defStyle, 0);

        final float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int defaultShadowHeightInPix = (int) (DEFAULT_SHADOW_HEIGHT * density + 0.5f);

        mShadowHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
                R.styleable.StickyScrollView_stuckShadowHeight,
                defaultShadowHeightInPix);

        int shadowDrawableRes = a.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.StickyScrollView_stuckShadowDrawable, -1);

        if (shadowDrawableRes != -1) {
            mShadowDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(
                    shadowDrawableRes);
        }

        a.recycle();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the height of the shadow drawable in pixels.
     *
     * @param height
     */
    public void setShadowHeight(int height) {
        mShadowHeight = height;
    }


    public void setup(){
        mStickyViews = new ArrayList<View>();
    }

    private int getLeftForViewRelativeOnlyChild(View v){
        int left = v.getLeft();
        while(v.getParent() != getChildAt(0)){
            v = (View) v.getParent();
            left += v.getLeft();
        }
        return left;
    }

    private int getTopForViewRelativeOnlyChild(View v){
        int top = v.getTop();
        while(v.getParent() != getChildAt(0)){
            v = (View) v.getParent();
            top += v.getTop();
        }
        return top;
    }

    private int getRightForViewRelativeOnlyChild(View v){
        int right = v.getRight();
        while(v.getParent() != getChildAt(0)){
            v = (View) v.getParent();
            right += v.getRight();
        }
        return right;
    }

    private int getBottomForViewRelativeOnlyChild(View v){
        int bottom = v.getBottom();
        while(v.getParent() != getChildAt(0)){
            v = (View) v.getParent();
            bottom += v.getBottom();
        }
        return bottom;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        if(!mClipToPaddingHasBeenSet){
            mClippingToPadding = true;
        }
        notifyHierarchyChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void setClipToPadding(boolean clipToPadding) {
        super.setClipToPadding(clipToPadding);
        mClippingToPadding = clipToPadding;
        mClipToPaddingHasBeenSet = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child) {
        super.addView(child);
        findStickyViews(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index) {
        super.addView(child, index);
        findStickyViews(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, index, params);
        findStickyViews(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int width, int height) {
        super.addView(child, width, height);
        findStickyViews(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, params);
        findStickyViews(child);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        if(mCurrentlyStickingView != null){
            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(getPaddingLeft() + mStickyViewLeftOffset, getScrollY() + mStickyViewTopOffset + (mClippingToPadding ? getPaddingTop() : 0));

            canvas.clipRect(0, (mClippingToPadding ? -mStickyViewTopOffset : 0), getWidth() - mStickyViewLeftOffset,mCurrentlyStickingView.getHeight() + mShadowHeight + 1);

            if (mShadowDrawable != null) {
                int left = 0;
                int right = mCurrentlyStickingView.getWidth();
                int top = mCurrentlyStickingView.getHeight();
                int bottom = mCurrentlyStickingView.getHeight() + mShadowHeight;
                mShadowDrawable.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
                mShadowDrawable.draw(canvas);
            }

            canvas.clipRect(0, (mClippingToPadding ? -mStickyViewTopOffset : 0), getWidth(), mCurrentlyStickingView.getHeight());
            if(getStringTagForView(mCurrentlyStickingView).contains(FLAG_HASTRANSPARANCY)){
                showView(mCurrentlyStickingView);
                mCurrentlyStickingView.draw(canvas);
                hideView(mCurrentlyStickingView);
            }else{
                mCurrentlyStickingView.draw(canvas);
            }
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if(ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            mRedirectTouchesToStickyView = true;
        }

        if(mRedirectTouchesToStickyView){
            mRedirectTouchesToStickyView = mCurrentlyStickingView != null;
            if(mRedirectTouchesToStickyView){
                mRedirectTouchesToStickyView =
                        ev.getY()<=(mCurrentlyStickingView.getHeight()+ mStickyViewTopOffset) &&
                                ev.getX() >= getLeftForViewRelativeOnlyChild(mCurrentlyStickingView) &&
                                ev.getX() <= getRightForViewRelativeOnlyChild(mCurrentlyStickingView);
            }
        }else if(mCurrentlyStickingView == null){
            mRedirectTouchesToStickyView = false;
        }
        if(mRedirectTouchesToStickyView){
            ev.offsetLocation(0, -1*((getScrollY() + mStickyViewTopOffset) - getTopForViewRelativeOnlyChild(mCurrentlyStickingView)));
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    private boolean hasNotDoneActionDown = true;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if(mRedirectTouchesToStickyView){
            ev.offsetLocation(0, ((getScrollY() + mStickyViewTopOffset) - getTopForViewRelativeOnlyChild(mCurrentlyStickingView)));
        }

        if(ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            hasNotDoneActionDown = false;
        }

        if(hasNotDoneActionDown){
            MotionEvent down = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);
            down.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
            super.onTouchEvent(down);
            hasNotDoneActionDown = false;
        }

        if(ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL){
            hasNotDoneActionDown = true;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        doTheStickyThing();
    }

    private void doTheStickyThing() {
        View viewThatShouldStick = null;
        View approachingStickyView = null;
        for(View v : mStickyViews){
            int viewTop = getTopForViewRelativeOnlyChild(v) - getScrollY() + (mClippingToPadding ? 0 : getPaddingTop());
            if(viewTop<=0){
                if(viewThatShouldStick==null || viewTop>(getTopForViewRelativeOnlyChild(viewThatShouldStick) - getScrollY() + (mClippingToPadding ? 0 : getPaddingTop()))){
                    viewThatShouldStick = v;
                }
            }else{
                if(approachingStickyView == null || viewTop<(getTopForViewRelativeOnlyChild(approachingStickyView) - getScrollY() + (mClippingToPadding ? 0 : getPaddingTop()))){
                    approachingStickyView = v;
                }
            }
        }
        if(viewThatShouldStick!=null){
            mStickyViewTopOffset = approachingStickyView == null ? 0 : Math.min(0, getTopForViewRelativeOnlyChild(approachingStickyView) - getScrollY()  + (mClippingToPadding ? 0 : getPaddingTop()) - viewThatShouldStick.getHeight());
            if(viewThatShouldStick != mCurrentlyStickingView){
                if(mCurrentlyStickingView !=null){
                    stopStickingCurrentlyStickingView();
                }
                // only compute the left offset when we start sticking.
                mStickyViewLeftOffset = getLeftForViewRelativeOnlyChild(viewThatShouldStick);
                startStickingView(viewThatShouldStick);
            }
        }else if(mCurrentlyStickingView !=null){
            stopStickingCurrentlyStickingView();
        }
    }

    private void startStickingView(View viewThatShouldStick) {
        mCurrentlyStickingView = viewThatShouldStick;
        if(getStringTagForView(mCurrentlyStickingView).contains(FLAG_HASTRANSPARANCY)){
            hideView(mCurrentlyStickingView);
        }
        if(((String) mCurrentlyStickingView.getTag()).contains(FLAG_NONCONSTANT)){
            post(mInvalidateRunnable);
        }
    }

    private void stopStickingCurrentlyStickingView() {
        if(getStringTagForView(mCurrentlyStickingView).contains(FLAG_HASTRANSPARANCY)){
            showView(mCurrentlyStickingView);
        }
        mCurrentlyStickingView = null;
        removeCallbacks(mInvalidateRunnable);
    }

    /**
     * Notify that the sticky attribute has been added or removed from one or more views in the View hierarchy
     */
    public void notifyStickyAttributeChanged(){
        notifyHierarchyChanged();
    }

    private void notifyHierarchyChanged(){
        if(mCurrentlyStickingView !=null){
            stopStickingCurrentlyStickingView();
        }
        mStickyViews.clear();
        findStickyViews(getChildAt(0));
        doTheStickyThing();
        invalidate();
    }

    private void findStickyViews(View v) {
        if(v instanceof ViewGroup){
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)v;
            for(int i = 0 ; i<vg.getChildCount() ; i++){
                String tag = getStringTagForView(vg.getChildAt(i));
                if(tag!=null && tag.contains(STICKY_TAG)){
                    mStickyViews.add(vg.getChildAt(i));
                }else if(vg.getChildAt(i) instanceof ViewGroup){
                    findStickyViews(vg.getChildAt(i));
                }
            }
        }else{
            String tag = (String) v.getTag();
            if(tag!=null && tag.contains(STICKY_TAG)){
                mStickyViews.add(v);
            }
        }
    }

    private String getStringTagForView(View v){
        Object tagObject = v.getTag();
        return String.valueOf(tagObject);
    }

    private void hideView(View v) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11){
            v.setAlpha(0);
        }else{
            AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
            anim.setDuration(0);
            anim.setFillAfter(true);
            v.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    }

    private void showView(View v) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11){
            v.setAlpha(1);
        }else{
            AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
            anim.setDuration(0);
            anim.setFillAfter(true);
            v.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to do is to adapt it to suit my needs, but I've tried poking around in this implementation to see how it does what it does and I cannot figure out how it gets the view to get stuck to the top of the `ScrollView`. Does anyone have any idea how this works?

## Edit:

Here is the layout that I want to apply this concept too:
*Keep in mind that the `Headers` (Headers 1 & 2) are custom `ViewGroups` that contains the `Sub-Headers` (Header 1a, 1b, 2a); which are also custom `ViewGroups` that contain custom views which are the `Items`.

[image]

Comment: If you want your view to stick to the top when you scroll passed it add a sticky tag with the android:tag="sticky" in your xml layout

Comment: Provide some graphics of your requirement. That will help to understand your requirement better.

Comment: @PN10 that's not how it sticks views to the top. that's how it identifies what to stick. i'm asking how the code works that makes it appear as if a view is stuck to the top.

Answer (score 6):

The `StickyScrollView` you are using is just saving a tag to whether it should be sticky or not and if not which child of scrollview is it's header, and according to that it is maintaining it as a first child view.
If you want to use this `StickyScrollView` only you have to modify it and maintain one more tag as sub-header.
I will suggest rather using this `ScrollView`, you can use [this ListView](https://github.com/Kenber/DoubleStickyHeadersList). It is very easy to implement and it works.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use [header-decor](https://github.com/edubarr/header-decor)  for your requirement. Internally its using `RecyclerView`, so it is advisable to use it. Check ***Double Header*** section in below gif.

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: that is nearly *exactly* what i want. the only issue is i'm using a `ScrollView` and not a `RecyclerView`. i edited the question and added the layout that i'm trying to apply this concept to. i'd gladly make this adapt for a `ScrollView` and share it. i just need to understand how to the implementation posted in the question does it.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't rocket science.  There's two key parts to understanding this.

First is in the method `doTheStickyThing`.  This figures out what goes where.

The initial step is figuring out which header to stick.  Once you scroll down, you have views both above and below the top of the scroll view.  You want to stick the bottom-most header that is still above the top of the scroll view. So you see a lot of expressions like this:

```
         getTopForViewRelativeOnlyChild(viewThatShouldStick) - getScrollY() + (clippingToPadding ? 0 : getPaddingTop()))
```

That resulting value is just the offset of the top of the view from the top of the scroll view.  If the header is above the top of the scroll view, the value is negative.  So it turns out you want the header that has the greatest offset value that is still less than or equal to zero.  The winning view gets assigned to `viewThatShouldStick`.

Now that you have a sticking header, you want to know which following header might start pushing that one out of the way when scrolling.  That gets assigned to `approachingView`

If the approaching view is pushing the header out of the way, you have to offset the top of the header. That value is assigned to `stickyViewTopOffset`

The second key part is drawing the header.  That's done in `dispatchDraw`.

Here's the trick to making the view look "stuck":  The normal rendering logic would like to put that header at a certain place based on its current bounds.  We can just move the canvas (translate) underneath that header so that it draws at the top of the scroll view instead of wherever it would normally draw. Then we tell the view to draw itself.  This happens after all the list item views have been already been drawn, so the header appears to float on top of the list items.

When we move the canvas around, we also have to take into account the case where another approaching header is starting to push this one out of the way.  The clipping handles some corner cases concerning how things should look when paddings are involved.

---

I started working on modifying the code to do what you wanted, but things got complicated fast.

Instead of tracking two headers, you need to track *three* headers: header, subheader, and approaching header.  Now you have to handle the top offset of the subheader along with the top offset of the header.  And then you have two scenarios: First is that the approaching header is a main header.  This is going to modify both top offsets.  But when the approaching header is a *sub*header, only the top offset of the pinned subheader is affected, and the main header offset stays the same.

I can get this, but I'm short on time right now.  I'll finish off the code and post it if I can find the time.

Comment: it's the `dispatchDraw` method that gets me. i toyed around with it a bit by commenting out all of its code except for the conditionals (i did comment out the body of the conditionals). i then uncommented only two lines: the `canvas.translate` and `mCurrentlyStickingView.draw` (in the else statement) lines, and it turned out the implementation still worked exactly as expected.

Comment: so it seems the important stuff is occurring on these two lines, but i don't understand how they're making the sticky view "stick" to the top. could you shed some light on what these two lines are doing? --mainly how they are working together because the sticky implementation doesn't work unless both lines are uncommented.

Comment: What if we don't want to draw and just move the translationY to the correct position so that we avoid drawing of the canvas on the view again and again. I am trying to stick a video and draw is causing it to flicker

Comment: The problem is that the `ScrollView` is continually drawing during scrolling, so the redraw is fixing the damage to the sticky header caused by the `ScrollView`.  That's why you're seeing flicker.
Video is special case because it's typically drawn with OpenGL on its own thread.  Getting video to cooperate might be tough.  I don't really have an answer for that.  If you haven't already, post a new question with all the details so that the entire community can have the opportunity to help you.